# How can I calculate the concentration of nanoparticles in water solution?

Tags: concentration, theoretical-chemistry, nanotechnology

I have synthesized gold-silver bimetallic nanoparticles in water media by following this [article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nl201796s).
How can I calculate the concentration of my nanoparticles solution?

Comment: Do you know how much gold and silver you added? And how much water you added?

Comment: Obviously you cannot, at least not in terms of number of entities per unit V. This would require to know the size of them, or the "nanoparticular" weight. It is a kind of surprise when sample are real and not always NaCl sugar and so on. It is similar polyeners, with all their mass distribution and aggregations. If you mean mass per volume see comment above.

Comment: In the current form, the original question provides too little information to answer the question.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Yes!It is possible to calculate the amount of gold, silver and water from the article.

Comment: It's pretty rare to synthesize a nanoparticle solution like that for the purpose of calculating its concentration. What do you want to do with the information about the concentration?

Comment: @chipbuster I have synthesized this kind of nanoparticles and also have functionalized them through thiol group. I want to know how many moles of thiol could be attach on each of the nanoparticles.